# Non Qt project (Cmake) - troubles with linking to library

Tags: cmake, static-linking, glfw

I freshly installed Qt Creator with MinGW and Cmake. I'm trying to play with OpenGL.
So far I got this code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(world_0)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
file(GLOB SRC_LIST *.cpp&#41;

find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(F:/u_qt/libs/glfw/glfw-3.0.1/include)
link_directories(F:/u_qt/libs/glfw/glfw-3.0.1/lib-mingw)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw3)
```

I've added FindGLFW3.cmake from ["FindGLFW3.make"](https://raw.github.com/zero57/CMakeScripts/master/FindGLFW3.cmake). But still got 'undefined reference' error.

I will be glad to hear any feedback from you guys. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FindGLFW3.cmake file you linked to, it looks like the last half of your CMakeLists.txt should be changed to something like:

```
find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: I would add that entering paths manually in a CMakeLists.txt file is a bad practice. It is the role of the cmake cache, which can be edited through cmake-gui, for example, to contain values that could not be computed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It disturbed a little:

```
Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.
```

But here it comes. I changed CMakeLists.txt to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(world_0)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
file(GLOB SRC_LIST *.cpp)

find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)
set(GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH F:/u_qt/libs/glfw/glfw-3.0.1/include)
set(GLFW3_LIBRARY F:/u_qt/libs/glfw/glfw-3.0.1/lib-mingw/glfw3dll.a)

include_directories(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW3_LIBRARY})
```

and with code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I got:

```
Starting F:\u_qt\projects\world_0-build\world_0.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
F:\u_qt\projects\world_0-build\world_0.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the 2 `set(GLFW3_...)` calls - that's what the `find_package(GLFW3 REQUIRED)` call is supposed to do.

Comment: However compiler choked that errors:

`CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLFW3_INCLUDE_PATH
   used as include directory in directory F:/u_qt/projects/world_0
GLFW3_LIBRARY
    linked by target "world_0" in directory F:/u_qt/projects/world_0`